# Loss function bounces back up

Tags: neural-network, lstm, loss-function

I'm training a very simple LSTM in PyTorch.  It's a single layer, and I'm using it for multi-label classification with a `BCEWithLogitsLoss`.  My batches are shuffled, I'm not using regularization yet, I'm using a constant learning rate, but every once in a while the loss makes a big jump up, and takes a long time to come back down again.

[image: Loss curve]

X axis is epoch, Y axis is log-loss.